# MySQL Left Join Count Activities and return null

Tags: mysql

Trying to get this `mysql` query to work.

Explanation: There are two tables, one with all projects with org id columns, the second has all activities with column projectid that relates to the project table. I would like to count all activities within the activities table that has the userid and is active with 1.
But here comes the tricky part, I cannot get working. It does not collect the projects that are missing in activities table and present these with count 0. I would like to show all project that correspond with a unique projectid within bo

```
SELECT p1.`id` AS projectid ,count(a1.`id`) AS activitiescount ,a1.`userid` AS userid ,p1.`orgid` AS orgid  
FROM `projects` AS p1 
LEFT JOIN `activities` AS a1 
ON p1.`id`=a1.`projectid` 
WHERE p1.`orgid`=3 
AND a1.`userid` = 26 
AND a1.`active`=1 
OR a1.`id` IS null 
GROUP BY p1.`id` 
ORDER BY p1.`name` DESC
```

Gives:

[image]

As you can see, the is not correct with 6 and 2 for example.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: move any limits on Activites to the join itself.  otherwise the left join behaves like an inner join; the nulls are eliminated becuase they are not userID 26 and active 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

Moved limits on Activities to the join.

Also the OR brought back more than you wanted, by moving the where clause around that problem should be resolved as well.

Standard Approach:

```
SELECT p1.`id` AS projectid 
     , count(a1.`id`) AS activitiescount 
     , a1.`userid` AS userid 
     , p1.`orgid` AS orgid  
FROM `projects` AS p1 
LEFT JOIN `activities` AS a1 
  ON p1.`id`=a1.`projectid` 
 AND a1.`userid` = 26 
 AND a1.`active`=1 
WHERE p1.`orgid`=3 
GROUP BY p1.`id` 
ORDER BY p1.`name` DESC
```

your approach w/ ()'s correctly placed.

```
SELECT 
    p1.`id` AS projectid 
    ,count(a1.`id`) AS activitiescount 
    ,a1.`userid` AS userid 
    ,p1.`orgid` AS orgid  

FROM `projects` AS p1 
LEFT JOIN `activities` AS a1 ON p1.`id`=a1.`projectid` 

WHERE p1.`orgid`=3 
  AND ((a1.`userid` = 26 AND a1.`active`=1)  OR a1.`id` IS null) 
GROUP BY p1.`id` 
ORDER BY p1.`name` DESC
```

----Update to simulate full outer join per comment.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT p1.`id` AS projectid 
     , count(a1.`id`) AS activitiescount 
     , a1.`userid` AS userid 
     , p1.`orgid` AS orgid  
FROM `projects` AS p1 
LEFT JOIN `activities` AS a1 
  ON p1.`id`=a1.`projectid` 
 AND a1.`userid` = 26 
 AND a1.`active`=1 
WHERE p1.`orgid`=3 
GROUP BY p1.`id` 
UNION  
SELECT p1.`id` AS projectid 
     , count(a1.`id`) AS activitiescount 
     , a1.`userid` AS userid 
     , p1.`orgid` AS orgid  
FROM `projects` AS p1 
RIGHT JOIN `activities` AS a1 
  ON p1.`id`=a1.`projectid` 
 AND p1.`orgid`=3 
WHERE a1.`userid` = 26 
 AND a1.`active`=1 
GROUP BY p1.`id`)
ORDER BY p1.`id`,A1.ID -- assumes A1.ID exists and you want to order in that fashion.
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, damn I've been struggling with this one. Now I've learned something new and how to achieve this in the future. Thanks mate!

Comment: When using an outer join, Generally speaking, only apply limits to the table showing all records.  Limits on the right side table of a left join should be placed on the join or the join acts like an inner join.  The OR clause here w/o ()'s was causing the bulk of your problem however.

Comment: Is it possible to also include activities within activities table that are null or not included among the projects?

Comment: in other RDBMS systems  this would be accomplished by using a full outer join instead of a left join.  MySQL implements these using a union and subqueries as it doesn't support full outer join (Example now included)